# Invalid Class String Using Excel 2010

Tags: c++, mfc, automation, excel-2010

I have a third-party legacy software that uses Automation to control MS Excel (using MFC/C++).  The code is straightforward:

```
_ApplicationPtr xl;
HRESULT hr = xl.CreateInstance("Excel.Application");
```

This worked perfectly since Excel 2000, 2002 (XP), 2003 and 2007; however, after installing Office 2010, the CreateInstance call fails with "Invalid Class String" (CO_E_CLASSSTRING).  Is there anything special I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The class string is the `"Excel.Application"` part, which, presumably, Microsoft has changed in Office 2010.

Normally, it's something like "Excel9.Application" for the "real" value, and "Excel.Application" pointing to the latest version specific entry.  It's possible the MS stopped adding the pointer entry, or your registry got messed up in the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, James.  I should mentioned that I tried the third-party software on a clean Win7 machine with only Office 2010 Home & Business and the software itself installed.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  I installed Office 2010 using the new Click-to-run method (because I downloaded the trial from MS' web site using the default option).  As soon as I download & install it using the MSI, all PROGID/CLSID are now in the registry (Excel.Application and Excel.Application.14) and my Automation works fine...

Comment: hey JoJoeDad (greetings, fellow canadian)--it sounds like Office Starter (because of click-to-run) doesn't support OLE automation.  can you confirm that you purchased/installed a copy of office to solve this problem?  thanks!